# Binary XML file line #44 in activity_login: Error inflating class TextView Android 12 issue

Tags: java, android, textview, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I've installed my app on an emulator with Android 12 and it crashes after splashscreen when trying to inflate the login activity. I have to mention that this issue is reproducing only on Emulator with **Android 12.**

The error says:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.total.tankapptmg/com.hectronic.mobile_terminal.activities.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44 in com.total.tankapptmg:layout/activity_login: Binary XML file line #44 in com.total.tankapptmg:layout/activity_login: Error inflating class TextView**

, but I'm not sure if it cause the problem. Please let me know if you have any suggestions

**Here is where I set the contentView in LoginActivity:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    appInitialized = true;

    //Set Screen Orientation if the device is a mobile phone
    if (SharedPreferencesUtils.getBooleanValue(this, SharedPreferencesUtils.MOBILE_DEVICE_FLAG_KEY))
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    else
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

   
    CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
    CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);

    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

    //set xml layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    //set fragment manager
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    loadingIcon = findViewById(R.id.loadingIcon);
    loadingIconContainer = findViewById(R.id.loadingIconContainer);

    navMenuBtn = findViewById(R.id.right_nav_menu_button);
    if (navMenuBtn != null){
        navMenuBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
            }
        });
    }
```

**Here is the logcat:**

```
2021-12-07 07:24:20.329 19383-19383/com.total.tankapptmg E/TypefaceCompatApi26Impl: Unable to collect necessary methods for class java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.graphics.FontFamily.<init> []
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2363)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1759)
    at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.obtainFontFamilyCtor(TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.java:321)
    at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.<init>(TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.java:84)
    at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi28Impl.<init>(TypefaceCompatApi28Impl.java:36)
    at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompat.<clinit>(TypefaceCompat.java:47)
    at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompat.create(TypefaceCompat.java:190)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
    at android.widget.TextView.resolveStyleAndSetTypeface(TextView.java:2241)
    at android.widget.TextView.setTypefaceFromAttrs(TextView.java:2212)
    at android.widget.TextView.applyTextAppearance(TextView.java:4174)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1675)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1028)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:99)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:95)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1065)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.hectronic.mobile_terminal.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:93)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3606)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3790)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2202)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7829)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:982)
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.total.tankapptmg/com.hectronic.mobile_terminal.activities.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44 in com.total
.tankapptmg:layout/activity_login: Binary XML file line #44 in com.total.tankapptmg:layout/activity_login: Error inflating class TextView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3633)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3790)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2202)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7829)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:982)
```

Here is my activity_login.xml file:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
tools:context="com.myapp.activities.LoginActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredWhiteIcon"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppCompat">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:src="@drawable/back_button"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity_toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/log_in_fragment_title"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/right_nav_menu_button"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/menu_icon"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/loadingIconContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loadingIcon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/textColorGrey"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/textColorGrey"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_background"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

EDIT: This is my font-style used for the Toolbar:

```
<font-family
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<font
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:font="@font/helveticaneuefont"
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:font="@font/helveticaneuefont" />
<font
    android:fontStyle="italic"
    android:font="@font/helveticaneueitalicfont"
    app:fontStyle="italic"
    app:font="@font/helveticaneueitalicfont" />
```

Comment: Can you please post your XML code for `activity_login`? From log, it seems you're using `fontFamily` incorrectly with `TextView`.

Comment: Sure, I've just added it to the question, please take a look. thanks

Comment: Have you added font family in styles.xml ?

Comment: <style name="ToolbarColoredWhiteIcon" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/helveticaneue_font</item>
    </style>

Comment: Here is the styling added to the Toolbar

Comment: I also added in the question the declaration of this font-family